# Is the HTML5 API for clipboard access available? And how do you use it?

Tags: html, clipboard

I'm trying to copy images into the clipboard using [ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) and pasting them into Outlook(or anywhere). It isn't working. I read [this link](http://pivotallabs.com/users/mrushakoff/blog/articles/2215-you-can-t-yet-programmatically-copy-an-image-to-the-clipboard-from-a-javascript-web-app), and according to it, [HTML5 API](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) is the only way to copy images into the clipboard using JS. I want to know how to use this, or if any browser actually supports this?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well for Webkit browsers anyway, Apple has [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/WebKitJavaScript.html) available called "Using the Pasteboard From JavaScript". I imagine by using the `setData` method you could also set image data as well as text. I hope this helps you.